# Difference of reaction between NBS/CCl4 and NBS/AcOH

Tags: reaction-mechanism

With NBS/$\ce{CCl4}$ allylic bromination occurs. But with NBS/$\ce{AcOH}$ bromination occurs on the alkene double bond. Why does this difference occur and how? I.e what will be the mechanisms of both?

Comment: I do not have the full the mechanisms, but with the $\ce{CCl4}$ there will be a radical mechanism, while in AcOH it involves ionic intermediates.

Comment: Why does AcOH support ionic intermediates?

Comment: Might be because AcOH is a polar protic solvent thus will solvate the ionic intermediates favorably.